# how to add subnet ids dynamically to an azure keyvault network rules

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I need help to add all the subnet ids to the network acls list. I have kept only the needed code below to keep the question simple.

```
variable "subnet_names" {
 type = list(string)
 default = ["subnet1","subnet2"]
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "subnet_ids" {
  count = length(var.subnet_names)
  name = var.subnet_names[count.index]
  virtual_network_name = "vnetname"
  resource_group_name = "kvrgname"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault"{

  network_acls {
    bypass = "AzureServices"
    default_action = Deny
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [ data.azurerm_subnet.subnet_ids[*].id ]
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is the underlying issue here? Are there any errors? If so, add them to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be (no need for brackets):

```
virtual_network_subnet_ids = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet_ids[*].id
```

Comment: I want to provide an another answer here ```virtual_network_subnet_ids = [for subnet in data.azurerm_subnet.subnet_ids : subnet.id]``` . I tested both are working fine.